# How can I open to a specific friend using Find My Friend?

Tags: ios, url, url-routing

I know the URL Scheme is

```
findmyfriends://
```

but how can I open to a specific person if he/she is already a friend? Is there a way to add a friend if he/she is not already a friend?

I prefer using a URL handler but can do JavaScript.  I'm trying to embed the code in a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can add friends via URL handler.